# What is the Language $L(0^*)$?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

While working on Formal Language Theory, I came across this expression:
$L(0^*)$. What is meant by this? I know that $0^*$ is the set of all strings over the symbol $0$. So is this language the set of strings $\{\epsilon, 0, 00, 000, 0000, \ldots\}$?

Edit: I came across this in Hopcroft's *Automata Theory, 3rd. Ed.* It's from exercise 7.3.4 on p.298. The relevant portion is that $L_1 = L(0^*)$, where $L_1$ is a CFL (I think).

Comment: I think so, it would be better if you tell us where you came across it.

Comment: @hhsaffar information added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, given a regular expression $R$, $L(R)$ denotes the language represented by this regular expression. In this case, $R = 0^*$ and the language is indeed what you think it is.